# Multi Thread Java Server

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

am currently working on a project where I have to build a multi thread server. I only started to work with threads so please understand me.

So far I have a class that implements the `Runnable` object, bellow you can see the code I have for the run method provided by the `Runnable` object.

```
public void run() {

    while(true) {
        try {
            clientSocket = serversocket.accept();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                DataOutputStream respond = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                respond.writeUTF("Hello World! " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                  //
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Bellow is the main method that creates a new object of the server class and creates a threat. initializing the Thread.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Thread(new Server(1234, "", false)).start();
}
```

I know this creates a new thread but it does not serve multiple clients at once. The first client need to close the connection for the second to be served. How can I make a multi threated server that will serve different client sockets at once? Do I create the thread on the `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`

Comment: You've got to create a helper class that implements Runnable and that handles the data stream interaction for one user. then in your main class, generate these helper classes with each socket accept, and run them in their own thread. Best if you use a ThreadPool to do this. Note that there are tutorials for this very thing, including one by Oracle, and I'm quite surprised that you haven't found any yet. Quite surprised.

Comment: search for a tutorial for ServerSockets. I'd bet that each good tutorial on this topic will describe your problem with a solution

Comment: You may need to work on your search terms. Try this Google search: [java socket communications tutorial multithreaded](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+socket+communications+tutorial+multithreaded). Or just click on my link. First hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.

from the docs:

Supporting Multiple Clients

To keep the KnockKnockServer example simple, we designed it to listen for and handle a single connection request. However, multiple client requests can come into the same port and, consequently, into the same ServerSocket. Client connection requests are queued at the port, so the server must accept the connections sequentially. However, the server can service them simultaneously through the use of threads—one thread per each client connection.

The basic flow of logic in such a server is this:

```
while (true) {
    accept a connection;
    create a thread to deal with the client;
}
```

The thread reads from and writes to the client connection as necessary.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html